# How do I programmatically set up branching logic in SharePoint survey list?

Tags: survey-list

I can programmatically create a survey list and add questions to it. How do I define branching?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it was an epic adventure into lands unknown, and I may have found your answer.

First of all, some background:

- Questions on a survey are represented by fields in a list (they all inherit from [`SPField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.aspx))
- Choices in a list (and a survey) are stored as an [`SPFieldChoice`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.aspx)

It seems the "Jump To" destinations are associated with the choice field, and can be accessed using [`SPFieldChoice.ChoicesJumpTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldchoice.choicesjumpto.aspx).

The strings in this collection are the Internal Names of the fields (that represent the questions) to jump to.

The position of the items in this collection specifically relate to the positions of the choices in their own collection (e.g. choosing the second option in the drop-down causes the survey to skip to the second field/question named in the JumpTo list).

Comment: Yep, that's what I ended up doing last year. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Better late than never. :)

Comment: lol... "epic adventure into lands unknown"